# /function.unserialize appearing at the end of my 404 URLS in Google webmaster tools

Tags: php, jquery, url, google-search-console

I had a huge increase in 404 errors found on my site in Google webmaster tools, when I took a look at the list of 404's I found that most of them had the same php function appended to the end of the URLS (  **/function.unserialize**  ), a function I don't think is even used across my whole site, (or could it be jquery?) either way does anyone know why this might be doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to be jQuery.
You perhaps have a PHP error:

`Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 172 bytes in ...`

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

> In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned
>   and E_NOTICE is issued.

Advices:

1) Fix the error reporting level. Your production website should not display errors. That will fix the symptoms.
2) Search what causes the problem. Some data is serialized wrong (perhaps some url parts in your case). Debug, find and kill the problem source.